# Searching for specific element in array

Tags: list-manipulation

This may seem like a very elementary question, but I am wondering how I can search an array for a specific number and have a truth value be returned, if that number exists in the array. In my specific case, I have a matrix, *t*, which has some dimensionality *n* x *n*, and for some *n*'s one of the eigenvalues is 1. I'd like a function that can tell me for a given *n* whether or not 1 is one of the eigenvalues (i.e. by returning 1 if it is, and 0 if it isn't).

Comment: If you really expect exact results, you can use `MemberQ`.

Comment: Something like: `Table[AnyTrue[EigenValues[t[n]], EqualTo[1]], {n, 1, 10}]`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Both answers were precisely what I needed, thank you so much!